# How to do a SQL self join with nulls

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am using MS SQL 2008.  My table looks like this:

```
| Name  | Code | Amt  |
| ----- | ---- | ---- |
| April |  A   | 1.23 |
| Barry |  A   | 2.34 |
| Barry |  B   | 3.45 |
| Cliff |  A   | 4.56 |
| Cliff |  B   | 5.67 |
| Cliff |  C   | 6.78 |
```

I need the output to be this:

```
| Name  | Code_A | Code_B | Code_C |
| ----- | ------ | ------ | ------ |
| April |  1.23  |  NULL  |  NULL  |  
| Barry |  2.34  |  3.45  |  NULL  |
| Cliff |  4.56  |  5.67  |  6.78  |
```

The NULLs can be zero.

With a self join I am able to get Cliff, but unable to get Barry and April because i'm using something like this which only outputs if all three conditions are available.

```
SELECT     a.Name, a.Amt Code_A, b.Amt Code_B, c.Amt Code_C
FROM       Table_1 as c INNER JOIN
                  Table_1 AS b ON c.Name = b.Name INNER JOIN
                  Table_1 AS a ON b.Name = a.Name 
WHERE     (a.Code = 'A') AND (b.Code = 'B') AND (c.Code = 'C')
```

Comment: It sounds like you want an outer join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `JOIN`s, I think a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) is more appropriate here:

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    [A] AS Code_A, 
    [B] AS Code_B, 
    [C] AS Code_C
FROM (
    SELECT Name, Code, Amount
    FROM Table_1
) t
PIVOT (
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR Code IN ([A], [B], [C])
) AS pvt
```

Comment: Was about to post a group by on a union solution.  This is cleaner.  +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

A completely sql engine agnostic way is:

```
select names.Name, 
   (select sum(a2.Amt) from amounts a2
    where a2.Name = names.Name
       and a2.Code = 'A') as AmtA,
   (select sum(a3.Amt) from amounts a3
    where a3.Name = names.Name
       and a3.Code = 'B') as AmtB,
   (select sum(a4.Amt) from amounts a4
    where a4.Name = names.Name
       and Code = 'C') as AmtC
from (select distinct Name from amounts) as names
```

Where you select the unique set of names, and then sum up amounts for each particular code in place.  This is more intended to be instructional as to how SQL works.

In practice, I wouldn't actually use this in your case -- `PIVOT` is going to be much more efficient for any engine that supports it.  As shown here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7cb0a/5

Comment: Thank you for the link to SQL Fiddle.  I've used JSFiddle in the past and I will definitely play with this in the future.